# How can data be leaking between these 2 concurrent transactions?

Tags: java, concurrency, hsqldb, jdbi

I've got a project running on java 8, spring boot 1.5.9, hsqldb 2.4.0, jdbi3-core 3.0.0. I'm writing tests to verify database behavior. One set of tests checks concurrency behavior.

My most basic test is somehow leaking data between 2 transactions, and I can't figure out why. I don't know if my test is flawed, jdbi is bugged, or hqsldb is fundamentally broken.

Connection url `jdbc:hsqldb:${...};create=true;hsqldb.tx=mvlocks;hsqldb.tx_level=serializable`

Note that tx=mvlocks and tx_level=serializable. Setting tx=mvcc so that tx_level becomes snapshot isolation doesn't change the outcome, which is even weirder since *snapshots* taken at the same time before any changes should *definitely* not be able to affect each other.

Test explanation:

1. create a table with 1 record
2. start 2 threads
3. in each, start a new transaction at the same time (ensured by CyclicBarrier syncing, verified by logging output) so that neither tx should be able to see the other's changes
4. in thread 1, insert a new row (total 2) and commit
5. in thread 2, count the number of rows

My expectation is that thread 2's transaction should only have 1 record in the table, since thread 2's transaction was started before thread 1's transaction was committed and the isolation level is set to serializable.

```
    CyclicBarrier syncLock = new CyclicBarrier(2);
    Runnable sync = Unchecked.runnable(() -> syncLock.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

    jdbi.useTransaction(tx -> {
        Queries queries = tx.attach(Queries.class);
        queries.create();
        // inserts a row with id 1
        queries.insert(1, 1);
    });

    CompletableFuture<Void> first = CompletableFuture.runAsync(Unchecked.runnable(() -> {
        jdbi.useTransaction(tx -> {
            assertThat(tx.isInTransaction()).isTrue();
            assertThat(tx.getTransactionIsolationLevel()).isEqualTo(TransactionIsolationLevel.SERIALIZABLE);

            LOGGER.info("first tx started");
            sync.run();

            Queries queries = tx.attach(Queries.class);
            queries.insert(2, 2);
        });
        LOGGER.info("first tx committed");

        Thread.sleep(100);

        sync.run();
    }));

    CompletableFuture<Integer> subject = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(Unchecked.supplier(() -> {
        int out = jdbi.inTransaction(tx -> {
            assertThat(tx.isInTransaction()).isTrue();
            assertThat(tx.getTransactionIsolationLevel()).isEqualTo(TransactionIsolationLevel.SERIALIZABLE);

            LOGGER.info("second tx started");
            sync.run();
            sync.run();

            Queries queries = tx.attach(Queries.class);
            // counts the number of rows
            return queries.count();
        });
        LOGGER.info("second tx committed");

        return out;
    }));

    // capture exceptions from either thread
    CompletableFuture.allOf(first, subject).get();

    assertThat(subject.get()).isEqualTo(1);
```

Output:

```
01:28:16.255 INFO  (SQL) [net.leaumar.samstock.integration.db.Queries] {main}: took <1ms to execute query create table test(id int primary key, foo int) with arguments { positional:{}, named:{}, finder:[]}
01:28:16.257 INFO  (SQL) [net.leaumar.samstock.integration.db.Queries] {main}: took <1ms to execute query insert into test(id, foo) values(:id, :foo) with arguments { positional:{0:1,1:1}, named:{foo:1,id:1}, finder:[]}
01:28:16.313 INFO  () [net.leaumar.samstock.integration.db.ConcurrencyTest] {ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2}: second tx started
01:28:16.313 INFO  () [net.leaumar.samstock.integration.db.ConcurrencyTest] {ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1}: first tx started
01:28:16.315 INFO  (SQL) [net.leaumar.samstock.integration.db.Queries] {ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1}: took <1ms to execute query insert into test(id, foo) values(:id, :foo) with arguments { positional:{0:2,1:2}, named:{foo:2,id:2}, finder:[]}
01:28:16.315 INFO  () [net.leaumar.samstock.integration.db.ConcurrencyTest] {ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1}: first tx committed
01:28:16.317 INFO  (SQL) [net.leaumar.samstock.integration.db.Queries] {ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2}: took <1ms to execute query select count(*) from test with arguments { positional:{}, named:{}, finder:[]}
01:28:16.318 INFO  () [net.leaumar.samstock.integration.db.ConcurrencyTest] {ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2}: second tx committed

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :1
Actual   :2
```

This basic jdbc test does not show this "read committed"-like behavior. The test is green, proving that serializable transactions started at the same time cannot see each other's changes even after committing:

```
@Test
public void transactionsAreIsolated() throws SQLException {
    @Cleanup
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    statement.execute(CREATE_TABLE);

    @Cleanup
    Connection c1 = dataSource.getConnection();
    @Cleanup
    Connection c2 = dataSource.getConnection();

    c1.setAutoCommit(false);
    c2.setAutoCommit(false);

    startTransaction(c1);
    startTransaction(c2);

    assertThat(count(c1)).isEqualTo(0);
    assertThat(count(c2)).isEqualTo(0);

    insert(c1, 1);
    assertThat(count(c1)).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(count(c2))
        .describedAs("read uncommitted")
        .isEqualTo(0);

    c1.commit();
    assertThat(count(c1)).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(count(c2))
        .describedAs("read committed")
        .isEqualTo(0);
}
```

Comment: Try running a select in your "subject" before awaiting the barrier (sync().run())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your JDBC test in Jdbi and it works:

```
@Test
public void transactionsAreIsolated() {
  try (Handle h1 = jdbi.open();
       Handle h2 = jdbi.open()) {
    h1.begin();
    h2.begin();

    assertThat(count(h1)).isEqualTo(0); 
    assertThat(count(h2)).isEqualTo(0); // locks h2's txn to the current snapshot

    insert(h1, 1, 1);

    assertThat(count(h1)).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(count(h2)).describedAs("read uncommitted").isEqualTo(0);

    h1.commit();

    assertThat(count(h1)).isEqualTo(1);
    assertThat(count(h2)).describedAs("read committed").isEqualTo(0);

    h2.rollback();
  }
}
```

From testing it appears that transactions do not actually lock to a database snapshot until you actually interact with the database within the transaction.

In the above test, we observe the row count through `h2` before inserting the row through `h1`. This interaction sets up a transaction snapshot, which is why your JDBC test worked.

However if we modify the above test to conclude the `h1` transaction before observing the count on `h2`:

```
@Test
public void transactionsLockToStateWhenObserved() {
  try (Handle h1 = jdbi.open();
       Handle h2 = jdbi.open()) {
    h1.begin();
    h2.begin();

    insert(h1, 1, 1);

    assertThat(count(h1)).isEqualTo(1);

    h1.commit();

    assertThat(count(h2))
        .describedAs("_now_ we're locked to a snapshot")
        .isEqualTo(1);

    h2.rollback();
  }
}
```

Your original test has two sync points (transactions started, transaction 1 committed), but it needs four to fully test your scenario:

```
@Test
public void concurrentTransactionsAreIsolated() throws Exception {
  CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);
  Runnable sync = uncheckedRunnable(() -> barrier.await(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

  jdbi.useTransaction(handle -> insert(handle, 1, 1));

  CompletableFuture<Void> first = CompletableFuture.runAsync(uncheckedRunnable(() -> {
    jdbi.useTransaction(tx -> {
      assertThat(tx.isInTransaction()).isTrue();
      assertThat(tx.getTransactionIsolationLevel()).isEqualTo(TransactionIsolationLevel.SERIALIZABLE);

      log.info("first tx started");
      sync.run(); // wait for both transactions to start

      insert(tx, 2, 2);

      log.info("first tx inserted row");
      sync.run(); // let the second txn check uncommitted reads
      sync.run(); // wait for second txn to check the uncommitted reads
    });

    log.info("first tx committed");
    sync.run(); // transaction closed, let second transaction check committed reads
  }));

  CompletableFuture<Integer> subject = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(uncheckedSupplier(() -> {
    int out = jdbi.inTransaction(tx -> {
      assertThat(tx.isInTransaction()).isTrue();
      assertThat(tx.getTransactionIsolationLevel()).isEqualTo(TransactionIsolationLevel.SERIALIZABLE);

      log.info("second tx started");
      sync.run(); // wait for both transactions to start
      sync.run(); // wait for first txn to insert

      log.info("second tx checking uncommitted read");
      assertThat(count(tx)).isEqualTo(1);

      sync.run(); // let the first txn commit
      sync.run(); // wait for first txn to commit

      log.info("second tx checking committed read");
      return count(tx);
    });
    log.info("second tx committed");

    return out;
  }));

  // capture exceptions from either thread
  CompletableFuture.allOf(first, subject).get();

  assertThat(subject.get()).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

Comment: the need for an initial query to actually start the isolation - I would never have thought of it :) Thanks